# How can we deal with a white logo that needs to be placed on a white background?

Tags: logo, color-theory, branding, black, white

Our brand has had its logo for several years and we like it. The only issue is now we need to place it on a white background, which obviously limits our options. What can be done (other than embossing it or using drop shadow) to set it out from the background?

We've attempted to invert the white before, but it looks terrible and we won't compromise it that way. The coloured part of the logo does change a lot depending on what product it's placed on.

We don't want to be bound by the limitations of the space the logo is placed inside, especially when wider modules and graphics are placed underneath it. Any help much appreciated.

[image: MEDiBrace logo standard]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reversing the white seems to be the logical thing to do. I don't think it "looks terrible".

[image]

If you feel the black is simply too heavy, I can see that. The black does create a visual which is more "hard" in nature.

Using a grey to more closely match the value of the color portion can help with balance. 40-50% grey seems to be a good range.

This is a 50% grey....

[image]

And 40% grey...

[image]

I guess, another (quick) option would be to merely add a stroke...

[image]

A 50% grey stroke may work best...

[image]

But I can see how some may feel a simple stroke causes a loss of impact.

If you're thinking a drop shadow, it will really only work if a stroke is also used.

[image]

Drop shadows on a logo come across "canned" and "easy" in most instances, at least to me. But it does help retain *some* impact.

Could use an "outer glow".. but ultimately that just ends up looking like a softer stroke....

[image]

And there's always....

[image]

[image]

In order to keep "Med" as the lighter portion of the mark.

Beyond this, it would take understanding of all current uses to generate something cohesive for the brand, but isn't dependent on a dark background.

Comment: Thank you Scott, for taking the trouble. We have considered the black many times in the past. Has always been shot down though. It's just too far away from the brand, completely transforms it. The strokes are a consideration, I think they have an impact over the shaded option (which again, seem to make it into something else).

Comment: I had a play around with just bevels and drop shadow and came up with this:
https://gyazo.com/25f9ab26014ffdd3ba57d190d25c77a0

Comment: There is a dramatic loss in impact with that of course, but it is more faithful to the pure white. I wish in hindsight more thought had been put into this originally!!

Comment: Shadows to boost contrast are typically a poor choice for me. They *always* just seem like an "addition" because contrast was poor. (But that's me `:)` ) If I *had* to do something and reversing the white wasn't an option... I think a 50% grey stroke works best perhaps - retains the white but makes it visible. And I would agree, not much thought was put into a brand if it *only* works on a dark background.

Comment: I think the 'outer glow', the 'MED' is lost, it's too light I guess. The reason a dark colour for the white is out is because it's too transformational. The solution becomes more complex because you're dealing with two elements. The former 'MED', which is *always* traditionally seen as lighter than the 'Brace' element, suddenly becomes the darker element, completely transforming it.

Comment: Could reverse colors.. Med in green, Brace in black... but that'd take some experimentation, since you say there are other colors beyond green.

Comment: Yes, the coloured part always copies the same main colour of the product it's placed on.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with @Scott that inverting the white elements and making them black is a valid choice.

Using drop shadows or other blurry effects in a logo seems like a no go to me. It's a bit bad taste and looks cheap. Also gives a lot of technical trouble with getting the gradient consistent in printing.

I would suggest either adding a thin green stroke to the white elements:

[image]

Or perhaps a thick black stroke to the whole logo:

[image]

(These suggestions are of course just quick sketches without any refinement.)

Comment: Thin same-colour stroke to the white elements seems a good possible option, indeed. Thanks, Wolff. It doesn't look too bad. The thick black stroke, no.

Comment: This won't be printed by the way. It has to go onto Amazon EBC. the modules that go under the logo module are wider, which is why it can't look confined to a limited width

Comment: I do like this solution. Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: https://gyazo.com/f0d1c90de1affb7a4b535c1521653854

Comment: I like the outer stroke, perhaps not *that* thick, but that's a decent direction.

Answer (score 0):

Full confession - I'm not a designer. But I tried some things and here's a thought...a slight green tint in the white lettering with a thin green stroke. Works on either a white background or black background:

[image]

[image]

At least you have the optional advantage of a 1 color logo! :)